# Restricting Java Compiler API

Tags: java, security, restriction, java-compiler-api

I'm thinking of creating an in-game code IDE that uses a more restricted version of Java, for instance I do not want it to use the I/O stream APIs. Is this even possible?

Also, inb4 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158429/compiling-and-running-user-code-with-javacompiler-and-classloader/). It still doesn't help with restricting ability, only stupid/evil students XD.

Answer (score 2):

You can custom your [java.policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html). You can set here the class that can be used in your Java application. If your students use a class that is not present in the policy a security exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Restricting the compiler is one possibility - but possibly not the easiest one. You could try to invoke your compiler with the [`-bootclasspath` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options), providing a slimmed-down version of the JRE's rt.jar. Then using forbidden classes (or actually: using classes not included in your restricted jar file) will give a compiler error.

Using the [runtime security manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/index.html) and giving only restricted permission to your students code is a better idea. Give the student's classes only the [permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html) they actually need (which is quite likely almost none, depending on the task to be solved), and they will not be able to do anything malicious, while still being able to use most of the standard API, as long as it doesn't interface with the outside system.

Of course, this still will not prevent an endless loop, which is [actually impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what you mean by "does not use". If the code written inside that IDE isn't allowed to access the stream APIs (and not the IDE itself), you can always provide your own classloader which can restrict access to classes or whole packages.